# how can I make a math model (function) from CSV multivariable problem

Tags: math, model

I'm making a code for bank loan optimization. In this problem I import a CSV with all the parameters (customer age, number of installments, loan amount, among others). First I need to model the multivariable function (there are 6 variables in total) and then apply this function in traditional methods such as quasi-newton and nelder-mead (it's for a university subject). For this I need to make a mathematical model [Math model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCZOh.jpg) in order to find this function. Can you help me?
This is how my .csv looks like when I open it with pandas [CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FURSl.png)
Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

I just did it.

```
x1=[1,1,1,1,1]

def func(x1):
    a=0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        w = 1/linhas*((y1[i]*x1[0]+y2[i]*x1[1]+y3[i]*x1[2]+y4[i]*x1[3]+y5[i]*x1[4]-z[i])**2)
        a = a + w
    return a
b = func(x1)
print(b)

result = minimize(func, x1, method="nelder-mead")
print(result)
```